# NUnit doesn't find tests in assembly

Tags: c#, nunit, mstest

I inherited an assembly with MSTest, but these tests were run using nunit-console on the build machine (not sure how it worked). So I decided to sort it out and change them to proper NUnit tests, but now nunit-console (or gui) can't find any tests. They run just fine using ReSharper test runner though. Any idea what could be missing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem; can run my tests from within VS.NET using TestDriven.NET, but my buildmachine doesn't execute them, although my fixtures are all public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for help, everyone. Upgrading to the latest NUnit framework fixed the problem (all the obvious things you suggested were OK).

Frederik Gheysels, you can try that as well I guess.

Comment: I've version 2.4.7; it seems that the latest version is 2.4.8 ... I'll give it a shot.  thx.

Answer (score 12):

Check:

- Is the class public?
- Does it have a public parameterless constructor (e.g. the default one if you don't specify any other constructors)
- Does it have the `[TestFixture]` attribute at the class level?
- Is each test public?
- Does each test have the `[Test]` attribute?
- Is each test parameterless?

I believe *some* versions of NUnit were able to find tests based on their names, e.g. `TestFooBarBaz()` without the `[Test]` attribute, but I don't know what the state of this is now - it could explain the discrepancy though.

Answer (score 1):

Are your test fixtures, classes and methods, public? They have to be for NUnit to find them.