# Nunit - doesn't discover tests [no error-message]

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

Unit refuses to dsicover or run my tests in an assembly. This is not the case where Unit produces an error message like "Unable to find test in assembly". It simply doesn't discover that I have tests.

I right-click the test-method and the test output shows:

Discover test started ------
Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,0260026)"

I have tried everything mentioned in this post: 
[NUnit doesn't find tests in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618292/nunit-doesnt-find-tests-in-assembly)

Upgrading is not a possiblity. The processor architecture settings are correct. My tests are public and have all the correct tags.

Here's some code from my project that I simply can't get to even execute. I know that because I have a break-point right at the beginning.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTestProjects
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SomeRandomTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldFail()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 0);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldPass()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the internal visual studio test explorer. Unit Framework version 2.5.9.10348, runtime version v2.0.50727. I have Unit Test Adopter installed. I've attempted reinstalling it with no success.

Comment: So what version of NUnit are you using? Without knowing that it's hard to try to reproduce the problem. What test runner are you using? (NUnit-gui? Something else?) What happens if you run nunit-console?

Comment: Without extensions, I don't think the VS test explorer will pick up NUnit tests... it'll be expecting you to be using microsofts testing framework, which uses `[TestClass]` and `[TestMethod]` attributes on the tests...

Comment: I should have nunit test adapter installed. How can I verify?

Comment: Your test Project should have a reference to Nunit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter if you've installed the adapter... or you could just try reinstalling it through nuget

Comment: The reference is there and I can confirm that the test adopted is installed. I tried reinstalling it from Extensions and Updates under Tools. Still no success.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You must either install the NUnit VSAdapter vsix extension, or add the adapter as  nuget package to your solution.

The latest version is the 2.0, and the vsix is available here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d

And the nuget package can be found here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/

More information on these options can be found in this MSDN ALM post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/11/part-3-unit-testing-with-traits-and-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2012-using-the-tfs-build-and-the-new-nuget-adapter-approach.aspx, which also points to two earlier posts.

If you look in the Output console window under Test, the adapter name and version is displayed there as it run.  If it doesn't come up, the adapter is not active.

If you run Resharper, ensure you have the latest 8.2 version, there has been conflicts earlier with the test adapters and resharper.

Even if you can't upgrade this project from NUnit 2.5.9 to latest 2.6.4, you can verify the adapters work correctly in a test project using 2.6.4.
I just checked on my own machine with NUnit 2.5.9, and that worked nice with the 2.0 adapter.

**Update:**

For VS2017 you dont install the NUnit VSAdapter vsix extension, instead install the NUnit 3 TestAdapter for Visual Studio 2012 (Update 1) onwards. This works with NuGet package: NUnit 3.9.0.

**Update 2 - June 2019**
Just released the 2.2 version of the NUnit2 Adapter. It should now work properly with SDK type projects, and with VS 2017 and 2019.

Comment: I had this problem, but I didn't understand how the pieces fit.  The NUnit Test Runner needs to be installed in the Visual Studio Tools/Extensions and Updates section. NUnit is then installed with the solution as part of NuGet,   Making sure the runner version is similar to NUnit.

Comment: That is one option, I assume you mean Test Adapter when you talk about Test Runner.  The Test Adapter version 2.0 works with NUnit 2.6.4 and earlier.  The Test Adapter 3.x works with NUnit 3 and above.  The Test Adapter can be either the vsix from the gallery, or the package from nuget.org.

Comment: @jeremy:  Not sure what you mean: The VS2017 works with the vsix adapters, both for NUnit2 and for NUnit3 with their respective adapters. It also works with the nuget versions of course.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments the 3.x adapter is intended for NUnit 3 and above; but note that if you have NUnit 2.x tests, they will not be picked up in VS2017 and above. In my case I spent quite a while before I realized I was dealing with NUnit 2 tests, which mysteriously remained not found, with no error message shown. You may need to upgrade your NUnit 2.x tests to 3.x to be found by the 3.x adapter as per @herb-f answer below.

Comment: This issue will also occur when your code base has dependencies on mixed versions of NUnit nuget package. I realised that I had forgotten to update one of my dependencies that was dependent upon a lower version of NUnit. I found this by navigating to one of the classes in visual studio and at the bottom of the file it displayed its dependencies clearly showing that NUnit was mixed

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem when upgrading from Visual Studio 2013 to VS 2017.
In my case, all the tests were written for NUnit 2 (not 3) and worked fine in VS 2013.  Once VS2017 was installed, none of the tests could be found.

The problem is that VS2017 did not automagically pick up the NUnit 2 install on my VM.

The solution was to install the Nunit 2 test runner by clicking on the Tools menu,
Tools | Extensions and Updates.  Next select Online on the right-hand list and then enter "NUnit" in the Search box.  You can then add the appropriate NUnit test runner.

This probably applies to all test runners except perhaps MSTest.

Answer (score 2):

Mine is just like the same, but the different was I created my project as VS UnitTest project and not a plain DLL. So I created a DLL and referenced all the nunit assemblies and the test are now discovered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue.My tests are not discovered. After installing NUnit3TestAdapter dll from nuget package manager resolved my issue.my visual studio version is vs2017.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
  Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be with NUnit30Settings.xml. I had this poroblem. In my case file was empty. I don't know what was the reason. I copied settings from NUnitSettings.xml to NUnit30Settings.xml. This solved my problem. Files with settings are in ...Users\[User]\AppData\Local\NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used TestCaseSource attribute. And passed wrong sourceName.

```
 [Test]
 [TestCaseSource("TestDataCaseSource")]
 public void SomeTest1(string DataName, ITestData testData)
```

After fixing it, all tests appears in Test Explorer

Answer (score 0):

For my case VS2017, after installation of Unit Test Adopter 3, I just add an updated version of the DLL to my solution using Nuget Package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check here .

1. Make sure we are referencing the right dlls to the test project. In our case it will be **NUnit3testAdapter**
2. We have to restart the visual studio in order for the newly installed extension to take effect .

Even after trying all of this and still it doesn't work Install it as part of **Tool**Extensions and then install the Nunit Test adapter.
this should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I can reproduce it with the example code provided if I have the NUnit and the MSTest Frameworks installed, which causes the issue of 0 tests found.

Once I removed MSTest.TestAdapapter and MSTest.TestFramework packages the example code above worked.

In my own code I then had to change my attributes from the MSTest to the NUnit attributes e.g. [TestClass] to [TestFixture].

So basically check you don't have any rouge conflicting packages added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason for the message "Discover tests finished - 0 found" was that I haven't run the updates to the Nuget packages.

Go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution and click on the Updates tab. From there you can update the newset updates to the Nuget packages you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had this error for over a day, looking everywhere, reloading all test nuget packages, etc.  I thought I needed to reinstall Visual Studio.  Dumb me, it turned out to be the buttons at the top of the test runner.  I had somehow selected a button which showed no tests.

Solution:
Click the buttons at the top of test explorer to ensure you get the right state.