# No test is available in MyProject.dll., but Test Explorer shows them

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit

I can't run Unit Tests in my project, for about 4 days ago, I've already tried a lot of solutions that's existing in SO, but nothing helped me.

> No test is available in Path\To\My\TestProject.dll. Make sure that
>   test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework
>   version settings are appropriate and try again.

Test Explorer shows my tests, but can't run them.

Btw. These are **WPF C# projects**.

I have test classes with test methods like this:

```
    [TestFixture]
    [Category("Something")]
    public class SomeTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void SomeMethodThatDoesntWork()
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
                Option savedOptions = new ....
...
```

- I have 3 projects in my solution, every project's **Target framework is .NET 4.5.2** and every project's **Platform Target is x64**.
- NuGet packages: NUnit 2.6.4 and NUnit3TestAdapter 3.12.0.

NUnit 2.6.4 because of I have some Attributes like ExpectedExceptionAttribute that is already removed in newer NUnit versions.

I've already set Test\Test Settings\Default Processor Achitecture to x64 and also tried x86.

Test Console Output:

[image]

Test Exlorer:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Resharper? If so, which version?

Comment: I do not use Resharper.

Comment: I guess you were using another version of VS, check do you have installed the NUnit VSAdapter in your IDE. I have had a similar problem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890768/nunit-doesnt-discover-tests-no-error-message) helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved my problem in about 2 days.

There was DLL dependencies which those Visual Studio couldn't notice and didn't show me any warning or errors. 
[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) helped me to find those dependencies of my DLLs.

So what I've learnt again? Visual Studio can be buggy and sometimes isn't really smart.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was:

- Go to and SELECT -> 'Test' Tab -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture -> x64**

Run tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/test-explorer-faq?view=vs-2017#test-adapter-nuget-reference) i may solve your problem.

Also, you can in latest version of NUnit you can change ExpectedExceptionAttribute attribute to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897450/8882410) (or other examples from comments) or just use following asserts:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => 
{
    // Test Code
});
```