# NUnit for monodevelop doesn't see tests

Tags: c#, nunit, monodevelop

I'm writing some code in c# in monodevelop. I have one project for the code, and another for testing. I've installed nunit for monodevelop, and in the testing project i have referenced the nunit framework i have in the packages. For some reason when i click the "run all tests" button all i get is that one test was ran succesfully, TestCase. I have the following code for instance:

```
[TestFixture ()]
public class Test
{
    [Test ()]
    public void AnotherTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual (2, 1);
    }

    [Test()]
    public void JustTesting()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual (3, 1);
    }
 }
```

Obviously I would expect both of these to fail but instead Nunit prints out that one test (named TestCase) was ran successfully, ignoring the tests i wrote (no error message). I know TestCase is the default constructor name for a test class, i deleted it to check if it was still the only test ran, and somehow it is. What could possibly be causing all of this? The closest question i found to mine is this one [NUnit doesn't find tests in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618292/nunit-doesnt-find-tests-in-assembly) but sadly none of the answers seem to help. I have Nunit version 3.6.0 but i tried other older versions as well.

Comment: What version of MonoDevelop are you using and what version of NUnit? Also look in the IDE log for any errors. Older versions of MonoDevelop do not support NUnit 3 but only NUnit 2.

Comment: @Matt Ward The Nunit is 3.6 but i also tried downgrading to 2.4.3. Monodevelop is 5.10. I dont see any error message in the IDE log.

Comment: What operating system are you running MonoDevelop 5.10 on?

Comment: @MattWard Ubuntu 16